# Reducing degrees of freedom of a Hamiltonian by restricting first integrals

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian $H$ with a first integral $C$. Then by fixing $C=0$ is it always possible to reduce the degrees of freedom by 1?

This is typically done in the reduction of the motion in the central force field. However I cannot find any literature on extension to the general case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first question has a positive answer: if there is a first integral, the space where the movement occurs can be reduced by 1. The most prominent example is when there is energy conservation, on which the system is restricted to a 2N-1 space.

The general case (2N dimensions) is treated in the same manner (see e.g. goldstein's Classical Mechanics). However, it is not true that if you have M first integrals, you can reduce the system to a 2N-M space. The [Poisson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) between then must be zero in order to you be able to reduce the dimension. In this case, the [constant of motions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constants_of_motion) are said *involution*.

In case you find N constant of motions involution, the system is said [integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system), and the movement is restricted to a N-dimensional torus.

Comment: The poisson bracket needs to be non-zero right? Suppose that the poisson bracket is zero of the first integrals $C_1,C_2$. Then we can find co-ordinates $x_1=C_1$ and $x_2=C_2$ by the Caratheodory-Jacobi-Lie theorem.

Comment: Also see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95909/symplectic-submanifolds-and-first-integrals